# SQL query to insert image file into MSSQL database using API: Python

Tags: python, sql-server, github, pypyodbc

In query sheet of MSSQL Server 2017 when we execute this command

```
insert into Register1 (logo) SELECT BulkColumn FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'C:\\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\Desktop\Capture.JPG', Single_Blob) as img
```

***Result:*** `(1 row affected)`

**From python shell:** After establishing with database correctly

```
import pypyodbc

cnxn = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};'
                    'Server=DESKTOP-C6RS3DO;'
                    'Database=demo2016;'
                    'uid=sa;pwd=sa')
print('connected <br/>')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

SQLInsertImg = "insert into Register1 (logo) SELECT BulkColumn FROM Openrowset (Bulk 'C:\\Users\PC\Desktop\Capture.JPG', Single_Blob) as img"
cursor.execute(SQLInsertImg)

cnxn.commit()
print("Query Inserted Successfully...!")
```

***Result will be:***

```
>>> SQLInsertImg = "insert into Register1 (logo) SELECT BulkColumn FROM Openrowset (Bulk 'C:\\Users\PC\Desktop\Capture.JPG', Single_Blob) as img"
>>> cursor.execute(SQLInsertImg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1626, in execute
    self.execdirect(query_string)
  File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1652, in execdirect
    check_success(self, ret)
  File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1007, in check_success
    ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, ODBC_obj.stmt_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)
  File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 975, in ctrl_err
    raise ProgrammingError(state,err_text)
pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\Capture.JPG" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).')
>>>
```

Then I modified the above code with

```
SQLInsertImg = "insert into Register1 (logo) SELECT BulkColumn FROM Openrowset (Bulk r'C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Capture.JPG', Single_Blob) as img"
```

**Results in:**

```
>>> cursor.execute(SQLInsertImg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1626, in execute
    self.execdirect(query_string)
  File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1652, in execdirect
    check_success(self, ret)
  File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1007, in check_success
    ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, ODBC_obj.stmt_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)
  File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 975, in ctrl_err
    raise ProgrammingError(state,err_text)
pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\Capture.JPG" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).')
```

How do we resolve the above issue i.e, works with MSSQL but not with python shell.

Tried with

```
SQLInsertImg = "insert into Register1 (logo) SELECT BulkColumn FROM Openrowset (Bulk r"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Capture.JPG", Single_Blob) as img"
```

**Result that I got:**

```
>>> SQLInsertImg = "insert into Register1 (logo) SELECT BulkColumn FROM Openrowset (Bulk r"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Capture.JPG ", Single_Blob) as img"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    SQLInsertImg = "insert into Register1 (logo) SELECT BulkColumn FROM Openrowset (Bulk r"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Capture.JPG ", Single_Blob) as img"
                                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> cursor.execute(SQLInsertImg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1626, in execute
    self.execdirect(query_string)
  File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1652, in execdirect
    check_success(self, ret)
  File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1007, in check_success
    ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, ODBC_obj.stmt_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)
  File "C:\Users\Vitriv-Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 975, in ctrl_err
    raise ProgrammingError(state,err_text)
pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'C:'.")
>>>
```

```
SQLInsertImg = insert into Register1 (logo) SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\\Capture.JPG', SINGLE_NCLOB) as img
```

```
>>> import pypyodbc
>>>
>>> cnxn = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};'
...                  'Server=DESKTOP-C6RS3DO;'
...                   'Database=demo2016;'
...                   'uid=sa;pwd=sa')
>>> print('connected <br/>')
connected <br/>
>>> cursor = cnxn.cursor()
>>> SQLInsertImg = insert into Register1 (logo) SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\\Capture', SINGLE_NCLOB) as img
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    SQLInsertImg = insert into Register1 (logo) SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\\Capture', SINGLE_NCLOB) as img
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `r"C:\mypath\......"`

Comment: @dsgdfg updated with double quotes could you see the results

Comment: okay, [Check this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c3ba4af7-bbb4-4471-815b-10b8a5403d8c/operating-system-error-code-3the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified?forum=transactsql) , so **You cannot access directories other than the server.**

Comment: @dsgdfg No its in the >>> SQLInsertImg = insert into Register1 (logo) SELECT BulkColumn FROM Openrowset (Bulk 'C:\\Capture', Single_Blob) as img
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    SQLInsertImg = insert into Register1 (logo) SELECT BulkColumn FROM Openrowset (Bulk 'C:\\Capture', Single_Blob) as img
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: `OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\\Capture', SINGLE_NCLOB)`

Comment: @dsgdfg Will you check the updated post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161693/discussion-between-dsgdfg-and-nishanth).